# Javascript remove leading zeros and decimal points from string

Tags: javascript, regex

searching for a regex to convert

0.015.000 -> 15.000

0.150.000 -> 150.00

015.000 -> 15.00

Comment: replace `^[0.]+` with `''`

Comment: Pick up a basic Regexp tutorial and go through it. One of the first things you'll learn is how to handle the "leading" part of your question; that would be the `^` symbol, which matches things at the beginning of the string. Did you learn that? Next, you'll learn about "character classes", which handle the "zeroes and decimal points" part of your question--it's a character class which is composed of, well, a zero and a decimal point, so `[0.]`. You'll learn about repetition counts like `+`, which mean one or more of something, so in this case `[0.]+`. Then just put it all together.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a programming problem the OP has made to apparent attempt to solve or even think about.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below `string.replace` function. Use `^` to tell the regex engine to do the matching operation from the start. By putting `0` and `.` inside a character class would match either 0 or dot.

```
string.replace(/^[0.]+/, "")
```

Example:

```
> "0.015.000".replace(/^[0.]+/, "")
'15.000'
> "0.150.000".replace(/^[0.]+/, "")
'150.000'
> "015.000".replace(/^[0.]+/, "")
'15.000'
```